# Dynamically pass a value in Junit test cases Elasticsearch CRUD Ops

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

i have created a JUNIT test case for elastic search CRUD operation i have given both my class file and code of JUNIT test case below. i have hardcoded the values inside code test case is there any possibility of passing the values dynamically to test case

**Employeeinformation.class**

```
package com.ElasticSearchCrud.ElasticSearchCrud;

import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class EmployeeInformation {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    //private List<Technologies> technologies;
   // private List<String> emails;


    public EmployeeInformation(String id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmployeeInformation{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**JUNIT test case for creating document in elasticsearch**

```
package com.ElasticSearchCrud.ElasticSearchCrud;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringBootTest
class ElasticSearchCrudApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

    }

    private EmployeeService Eservice;

    @Autowired
    public ElasticSearchCrudApplicationTests(EmployeeService service) {
        this.Eservice = service;
    }

    @Test
    void createProfile() throws Exception {

        List<Technologies> technologies = new ArrayList<>();
        technologies.add(new Technologies("xxx", "xxxx"));
        technologies.add(new Technologies("xxx", "xxx"));

        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        emails.add("xxx@gmail.com");
        emails.add("xxx@gmail.com");

        EmployeeInformation EmployeePost = new EmployeeInformation("5", "xx", "xx",technologies,emails);

        String Result = Eservice.createProfileDocument(EmployeePost, "elcrud");

        EmployeeInformation EmployeeGet = Eservice.findById("elcrud", "5");

        assertNotNull(EmployeeGet.getId());

        assertEquals(EmployeeGet.getId(), EmployeePost.getId());

        assertEquals(EmployeeGet.getFirstName(), EmployeePost.getFirstName());

        assertEquals(EmployeeGet.getLastName(), EmployeePost.getLastName());

        assert Result.equals("CREATED") || Result.equals("UPDATED");
    }

    @Test
    void findAll() throws Exception {

        List<EmployeeInformation> Emp= Eservice.findAll("elcrud");

        System.out.println(Emp.size());

        int Result = Emp.size();

        assertTrue(Result  >= 0 );
    }

    @Test
    void findById() throws Exception {

        EmployeeInformation EmployeeGet = Eservice.findById("elcrud", "2");

        assertNotNull(EmployeeGet.getId());

        assertNotNull(EmployeeGet.getFirstName());

        assertNotNull(EmployeeGet.getLastName());

    }

    @Test
    void deleteProfileDocument() throws Exception {

        String Result = Eservice.deleteProfileDocument("elcrud", "3");

        System.out.println(Result);

        assertEquals(Result, "DELETED");
    }

    @Test
    void updateProfile() throws Exception {

        List<Technologies> technologies = new ArrayList<>();
        technologies.add(new Technologies("xxx", "2020"));
        technologies.add(new Technologies("xxx", "2013"));

        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        emails.add("xxx@gmail.com");
        emails.add("xxx@gmail.com");

        EmployeeInformation EmployeePost = new EmployeeInformation("3", "JUnit", "Testing",technologies,emails);

        String Result = Eservice.updateProfile(EmployeePost,"elcrud");

        assert Result.equals("NOOP") || Result.equals("UPDATED");

    }


    @Test
    void search() throws Exception {

        List<EmployeeInformation> Emp=Eservice.searchByTechnology("xxx","elcrud");

        System.out.println(Emp.size());

        int Result = Emp.size();

        assertTrue(Result  >= 0 );
    }

    @Test
    void searchByName() throws Exception {

        List<EmployeeInformation> Emp=Eservice.findProfileByName("xxx","elcrud");

        System.out.println(Emp.size());

        int Result = Emp.size();

        assertTrue(Result  >= 0 );
    }

}
```

Above code working fine but instead of hardcoding the value with in test case have to pass it dynamically. Could any one please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: where would you expect to define the actual values (system properties, property file, etc...)?

Comment: Actually i am not aware of this this is the first time i am working in JUNIT but intention is to follow the best approach for this

Comment: Actually i have completed JUNIT test case of all My CRUD operation and it is working fine but the thing is i have hardcoded the values in my test cases

Comment: What is your take on this Beppe?

Comment: See my answer then, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is OK to hardcode values in your unit testing, it is actually a good practise so you can see very clearly input/output of your test cases.
Sometimes it might not be possible as your code requires unique values (for example creating a new User in the DB) or special cases, in this case you have few options:

- use mocks (see Mockito) to avoid the interaction with the DB
- generate random values (still in your test code)
- read the values from your property file or POM file (as system variables)

Comment: Added my whole test case for your reference kindly verify and let me know where and all i can make a change to improve the Quality of the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any clarifications needed let me know. This test case is for doing an CRUD operations in elasticsearch using java

Comment: Sure

EmployeeInformation: remove commented out code, move toString() at the bottom

ElasticSearchCrudApplicationTests: match test methods names with the service methods, for example the test method would be searchByTechnology

Comment: Done! in this scenario no need of using Mocks and Mockito am i right?

Comment: Also i wanted to know, is there any specific way of handling negative scenarions of Test cases?

Comment: You are testing a service class so you dont mock that, thats correct (you could mock a class which is used by the service if needed)

Negative scenarios? You can test for expected exceptions (thats a valid case) or for test returning no results for certain search criteria

Comment: Thanks Beppe, will remind you if i found any bottlenecks, probably i will mark this post as solution once i have completed all my tasks related to test cases. Thanks a lot once again